# Spring Security 6

Tags: mysql, angular

I am getting the following error when trying to delete a record from my crud application.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/angular/deleteUser?id=3}' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED.

But in Postman I get 401 unauthorized error.
complete code is available in GitHub https://github.com/TommyStephen/SpringSecurity6.git
Grateful if somebody could advise me how to rectify it.

I tried everything I could

Comment: It will be good if you'll provide the configuration class where you configure security

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure CORS in WebMvcConfigurer.

Configuring:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Slf4j
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")  // Allow requests from any origin. You can district access from a certain IP here
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
        log.info("CORS configured to allow requests from any origin.");
    }
}
```

You have to notice that the solution opens up your server to potential CSRF attacks. One of the solutions is determining the certain IP in origins

```
            .allowedOrigins("http://167.172.244.194", "http://example.com") // Add the specific IP addresses or domains here
```

Comment: thanks for your advice hhrzc.  CORS issue got sorted out.  All end points except deleteUser works fine.  Gets 401 error for angular/deleteUser.  Is DELETE a special case?

Comment: @Tom I have investigated your code and determined the following line: `"angular/signup", "angular/login", "angular/findAllUsers"...`. I have suspicions you have to add the "angular/deleteUser" there. (SpringSecurityConfig)